# How to use the Xbox button on Xbox controllers to do some action with my PC?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers, xbox-one

I would like to use the Xbox button to launch games or take screenshots on my PC. Is is possible to map the Xbox button? Using a third party software, for example?

Comment: AFAIK I do not think so, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. pinumbernumber on reddit wrote [a program that allows you to map the Xbox Guide button](http://www.reddit.com/r/emulation/comments/1goval/any_way_to_map_the_middle_xbox_360_button/camujj7).

Comment: Can anyone explain the down vote? I realize link-only answers are usually discouraged, but I don't see how I could say much more on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows 8.1; actually there is already a functional software that can do it well:

[XBStart](http://xbstart.info/index.htm)

You can use it to control your computer by opening and navigating the Start Screen. Then you can do whatever you should do with a mouse and the Start Screen.

[XBStart Features](http://xbstart.info/features.htm)

For the moment the software isn't working on Windows 10, but the developer is working on it:

[XBStart 2.1.9 stable - navigate Windows 8.1 with an Xbox controller](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170773-xbstart-219-stable-navigate-windows-81-with-an-xbox-controller/page-8)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to use it and why it is useful?

Comment: You must install it, then you will be able to open Start Screen and navigate on it.